# CKeditor failing in Active Admin in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor, asset-pipeline, activeadmin

I have installed the ckeditor gem, and have [followed these instructions](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Ckeditor-integration) to get it integrating with Active Admin in Rails 3.2.3

Works a charm in development, but in production it fails. It seems to stutter when trying to load the config.js.

In development, it loads fine annd has the path `/assets/ckeditor/config.js?t=C3HA5RM`
In production it tried and fails to load the path `/admin/pages/3/config.js?t=C3HA5RM` (page ID is arbitrary)

The site is deployed using Capistrano, and so it theoretically exactly the same in development as it is in production.

How could these paths be incorrect, how might I change them? Could it have something to do with the asset pipeline perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Check in your console if `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` has a value. If not, you need to make sure it does before your form is rendered.

I achieved this by adding:

```
var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/assets/ckeditor/';
```

to **active_admin.js** before the line

```
//= require active_admin/base
```